# Удалить option из select с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

Как удалить `option` c `id="2"` из `select`

Смотрел примеры c `remove()` и `removeChild()` , но не могу подобраться , голова уже не варит...

Нужен вариант под все браузеры , судя по всему это `removeChild()`

```html
<form name="myform">
<select id="myselect">
<option id="1">ID 1</option>
<option id="2">ID 2</option>
<option id="3">ID 3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var select = document.getElementById('myselect');
select.removeChild(select.querySelector('[id="2"]'));
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <select id="myselect">
    <option id="1">ID 1</option>
    <option id="2">ID 2</option>
    <option id="3">ID 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если немного переработать код `@Cheg`, то можно так с одним поиском в `dom`

```js
let option = document.getElementById('1');
option.parentNode.removeChild(option);
```

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option id="1">ID 1</option>
    <option id="2">ID 2</option>
    <option id="3">ID 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```